# How to convert this .htacess to nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

I need to convert

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /generate
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?file=$2
```

To nginx conf

Can anyone help me with this?
Important:
The htaccess was in a folder called generate 
Give me a suitable code that will replace the htaccess in that folder 
Please show me exact code , looks complicated for me:)

Comment: Put at least some effort into trying, or go hire a consultant.

Comment: I converted the rest of the .htaccess . I am having problem with only this part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first time, you can try something like this:

```
    location /generate {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/generate/(.*)/(.*)/ /generate/index.php?file=$2;
        }
    }
```

but it is [not recommended](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).

Using [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) instead:

```
    location /generate {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
    }

    location @fallback {
        rewrite ^/generate/(.*)/(.*)/ /generate/index.php?file=$2 last;
    }
```